# Browser difference in displaying SVG RTL text with bidi-override and text-anchor="end"

Tags: svg

I'm noting a difference between browsers in displaying text forced right-to-left and also using text-anchor="end".

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" > 

    <text x="10" y="50" font-size="30" font-family="sans-serif" writing-mode="rl" direction="rtl" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" text-anchor="end" stroke="green" fill="green">
        Force RTL
    </text>
</svg>
```

In Chrome(v 27.0.1453.93 m) and I.E.(v 9.0.8112.16421), the text is shown as I would expect, with glyph stroking starting from the end point of the text and progressing to the left.  With the example above, it is displayed in the upper left corner of the browser.

In Firefox (v 20.0.1) glyph stroking, with text-anchor="end", is starting from the start point of the text and the display is off the page.  If I remove the text-anchor attribute, Firefox displays as Chrome and I.E. do ***with*** the text-anchor.

My questions are

1. Does anyone understand what's happening here?  Or is this a FF bug?
2. If there's no work-around, how can I switch between user-agents in the SVG so for Firefox, I can avoid using the text-anchor?

Thanks very much

Comment: do you know anything about right to left languages like persian, arabic, hebrew?

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/text-element.html

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Firefox. Fortunately it will be fixed reasonably soon (not sure exactly when) as we're revamping/rewriting text support in SVG. If you want to see it working properly, download a [Firefox nightly](http://nightly.mozilla.org/) type about:config in the URL bar and set svg.text.css-frames.enabled to true. So be careful about user agent tests because this will get fixed before too long.